# How do you serve a dynamically downloaded image to a browser using flask?

Tags: python, flask

I'm working with an IP camera. I can use a URL such as this one to grab a static image off the camera:

http://Username:Password@IP_of_Camera:Port/streaming/channels/1/picture

What I want to do is have python/flask download the image from that URL when the client loads the page, and embed the image into the page using an img tag.

If I have a template that looks something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="{{ image }}">
    </body>
</html>
```

how do I replace the {{ image }} with the downloaded image?

Would I use urllib/requests to download the image to flask's static folder, replace {{ image }} with something like `{{ url_for('static', filename="temp_image.png") }}`, and then delete the image from the static folder when the page loads? Would I download it someplace else instead (other than the static folder)? Or is there some other way to do it that keeps the image in memory?

PS. I know it's possible to replace {{ image }} with that URL directly, but that reveals the username/password/IP/port of the camera to the client.

Answer (score 6):

I would add a masking route on flask that fetches and serves the image directly.
Lets say `domain.com/image/user1/cam1`

Your server would typically make a http request to the camera and once it receives a response, you can straight up serve it as a `Response` object with appropriate mimetype.

In this case, the image you fetched from camera resides in your RAM.

```
@app.route('image/<userID>/<camID>')
def fun(userID,camID):
    #  fetch the picture from appropriate cam
    pic = requests.get('http://'+
        'Username:Password'+ # dynamically replace user id / password/ auth
        '@IP_of_Camera:Port'+ #dynamically replace port / IP
        '/streaming/channels/1/picture')

    # do processing of pic here..

    return Response(pic,mimetype="image/png")
```

However, if this image needs to be served over and over again, then you might wanna cache it.  In which case, I would pick something closer to your approach.

If you want to stream the camera images, it is a whole different ballgame.

Comment: This is if you want to let the user download the image, rather than embed it into an <img> tag, right? Or is there a way to use this to embed it into the <img> tag?

Comment: I am almost sure one should also be able to use it in <img> tags. I will make a quick test and post back.

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
url = "http://Username:Password@IP_of_Camera:Port/streaming/channels/1/picture"
response = requests.get(url)
if response.status_code == 200:
    f = open("/your/static/dir/temp.png", 'wb')
    f.write(response.content)
    f.close()
```

`{{ url_for('static' filename="temp.png") }}`

Not sure why you would need to delete it, but I guess you could if you thought that was required

Comment: I would delete it because every time you reload the page, it would grab a fresh image off the camera - there's no reason to store the old images - they would just take up space. Dynamically changing what is in flask's "static" folder is not going to break anything in flask?

Comment: I think everytime you refresh/reload the route, it will grab the new image and overwrite temp.png.  Flask isnt async so it should wait until requests downloads the image and writes it to disk before it serves it up.  I havent tested any of this, but that would be my inkling.